# Javascript doesn´t show input tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in html:

```
<div class="uif-col-3">
                <div id="id_SearchSuppliersByDocumentNumber">
                    <label class="control-label">@Global.EnterDocumentNumber:</label>

                      <input class="uif-autocomplete" type="text" data-source= @Url.Action("GetSuppliersByDocumentNumber", "Common")
                           data-displaykey="DocumentNumber" onkeypress=" return JustNumbers(event, this); " maxlength="20"
                           placeholder='@Global.EnterDocumentNumber' id="SearchSuppliersByDocumentNumber"
                           name="SearchSuppliersByDocumentNumber" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
                <div id="id_SearchAgentByDocumentNumber">
                    <label class="control-label">@Global.EnterDocumentNumber:</label>
                    <input class="uif-autocomplete" type="text" data-source="@Url.Action("GetAgentByDocumentNumber", "Common")"
                           data-displaykey="DocumentNumber" onkeypress=" return JustNumbers(event, this); " maxlength="20"
                           placeholder='@Global.EnterDocumentNumber' id="SearchAgentByDocumentNumber"
                           name="SearchAgentByDocumentNumber" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="uif-col-3">
                <div id="id_SearchSuppliersByName">
                    <label class="control-label">@Global.EnterName:</label>
                    <input class="uif-autocomplete" type="text" data-source="@Url.Action("GetSuppliersByName", "Common")"
                           data-displaykey="Name" placeholder='@Global.EnterName' id="SearchSuppliersByName" maxlength="60"
                           name="SearchSuppliersByName" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
                <div id="id_SearchAgentByName">
                    <label class="control-label">@Global.EnterName:</label>
                    <input class="uif-autocomplete" type="text" data-source="@Url.Action("GetAgentByName", "Common")"
                           data-displaykey="Name" placeholder='@Global.EnterName' id="SearchAgentByName" maxlength="60"
                           name="SearchAgentByName" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

and Javascript:

I´m able to show the text:

```
 $("#id_SearchSuppliersByName").css("display", "block");
                    $("#id_SearchSuppliersByDocumentNumber").css("display", "block");
```

but I can´t show the input tag:

```
$("#id_SearchSuppliersByName").val("");
                    $("#id_SearchSuppliersByDocumentNumber").val("");
```

Any ideas? I try also with show() but doesn´t work

Comment: Why are you using val with a div?

Comment: What do you mean by "show the input tag"?  What are you trying to do?  The code is attempting to set the *value* of a `<div>`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `hidden="hidden"` attribute from the input. Hide the div instead if you are looking to control the visibility using the div's ID.